# ServerUnauthorizedAccessException when trying to connect to Project Server through CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, csom, project-server

I have Microsoft SharePoint 2013 **onPremise** Farm with Microsoft Project Server 2013 installed on it.

I am trying to build a WebPart which should connect to the Project Server through CSOM from a TeamSite to get Project Information.

This is my super simple code:

```
string pwaPath = "http://sp2013/PWA";
ProjectContext projContext;

projContext = new ProjectContext(pwaPath);

projContext.Load(projContext.Projects);
projContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

When trying to execute it i get the following error:

`ServerUnauthorizedAccessException`

When i add

```
projContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "pass", "domain");
```

It works! But how can i make the code using the logged in user, cause the credentials passed above are the users credentials who is currently logged in.

Comment: The problem is the way you create the ProjectContext. I am not very familiar with Project Server, and hence - ProjectContext. However, in SharePoint apps, when you want to create a ClientContext which impersonates the current user, you do something like `var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostUri, HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity);`

Comment: Hi Hristo, i am trying to create a farm solution and therefore i do not have TokenHelper class. Isnt this possible within a farm solution?

Comment: Hi. Not sure about that. But think about the following: Can you change your web part code, so that you use JSOM, instead of CSOM? That way it will execute in the browser, with the current user credentials. Otherwise you have to be looking at user impersonation and in my experience that's never as easy as you'd like to.

Comment: @HristoYankov the code you've provided is used to create `ClientContext` with app identity. Not every CSOM code must be an app.

Comment: If you have the SharePoint Server and the Project Server installed on the same box, and you build your web part on the server side, why do you want to use the client object model? I think the server side object model (not very well documented, because MS pushes the client side APIs because of SharePoint / Project Online) is a better way for such cases. See the PSContext class and its properties (like Projects, EnterpriseResources, etc.) implemented in the Microsoft.ProjectServer.dll assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work because farm solution does not execute in the context of the SharePoint user. If you check [`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see that current identity is IIS built-in `IUSR`. This is the identity `ClientContext` will use to issue the request.

If you elevate permissions using [`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges%28v=office.15%29.aspx) code will be executed with app pool identity. This may be enough in some scenarios, but may also be not secure, as all users will be able to access the resources.